# React JS Development Build Showing a White Screen

Tags: reactjs

I am using a MacBook Pro with Big Sur 11.6.4 and with Node 17.6.0. Before the White Screen my Code was like this:

**Navbar.component.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
Nav,
NavLink,
Bars,
NavMenu,
NavBtn,
NavBtnLink,
} from './NavbarElements';

const Navbar = () => {
return (
    <>
    <Nav>
        <Bars />
        <NavMenu>
    <NavLink to='/' activeStyle>
            Home
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/about' activeStyle>
            About
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/browse' activeStyle>
            Browse
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/sign-up' activeStyle>
            Sign Up
        </NavLink>
        </NavMenu>
        <NavBtn>
        <NavBtnLink to='/signin'>Sign In</NavBtnLink>
        </NavBtn>
    </Nav>
    </>
);
};

export default Navbar
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar/Navbar.component';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'
import logo from './logo.svg';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';
import Footer from './Components/Footer';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Router><Navbar /></Router>
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            <Button variant="contained">Learn React</Button>
          </a>
        </header>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
      )
    }
}

export default App;
```

When I made some changes afterwards when I decided to add some routing to the Navbar.jsx file making it look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
Nav,
NavLink,
Bars,
NavMenu,
NavBtn,
NavBtnLink,
} from './NavbarElements';

import { BrowserRouter as  Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Browse from '../../Pages/Browse/Browse'
import About from '../../Pages/About/About'

const Navbar = () => {
return (
    <>
    <Nav>
        <Bars />
        <NavMenu>
    <NavLink to='/' activeStyle>
            Home
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/about' activeStyle>
            About
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/browse' activeStyle>
            Browse
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to='/sign-up' activeStyle>
            Sign Up
        </NavLink>
        </NavMenu>
        <NavBtn>
        <NavBtnLink to='/signin'>Sign In</NavBtnLink>
        </NavBtn>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/browse" element={<Browse />} />
      </Routes>
    </Nav>
    </>
);
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Navbar />, rootElement);

export default Navbar
```

[Error Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxrVV.png)

[Error Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2fCY.png)

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

> Im Sorry if this is a silly mistake. I am just starting to learn react. My apologies if this might feel like a waste of time.

Comment: You're importing `BrowserRouter as  Route`, which means that when you're using `Route`, you're actually using `BrowserRouter`. You should import both, and wrap everything you have inside a BrowserRouter.

Comment: @ShamPooSham Well, I just changed the code to your suggestion, and apparently it still does not work...

Comment: I assume you get another error now though, right? Please update your post with the new code and the new errors. Please post the new error messages too, and type out the first error message in your post so that it's searchable.

Comment: Also I'm not sure about the relevancy of having the old code in the post. You can remove that part to not confuse people

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

**STEP 1**

I just had to remove all other instance of `<Route path='' element={}>` and anything related to it on other files in the project.

**STEP 2**

Next, I needed to reformat the `App.js` making it look like this:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from './Pages/Home/Home.jsx';
import Browse from './Pages/Browse/Browse.jsx'
import About from './Pages/About/About.jsx'
import Footer from "./Components/Footer.jsx";

import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar/Navbar.component.jsx";

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' exact component={<Home/>} />
        <Route path='/browse' component={<Browse/>} />
        <Route path='/about' component={<About/>} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer/>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**RESULT**

I ended up with two errors left and one *GOOD* warning:

[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfBKt.png)

So, Thats it.

Comment: BTW, Its a good warning because it shows me everything is working, and i just need to add one minor thing.